# Need to update contacts on user's Microsoft Outlook, do they really need to have an Active Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Every documentation or tutorial I follow on how to programatically access Outlook's API seems to point to the same pattern:

Application redirects user to Azure so he can authorize (OAuth) the app access to his account's data.

Every time Azure Active Directory is mentioned as a cloud-based credential/access manager.

I'm having a hard time to understand why exactly AD is even needed. And even if it is, that means that should a company desire to integrate an application with the employees calendars, for example, they would need to have an AD just for authentication purposes? Does this make sense if I want to publish an application on Azure for any kind of customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Office 365 customer has an Azure AD for authentication. If you want to get at users contacts in O365 you have to authenticate using Azure AD.

If you want to get at contacts in Outlook.com, Microsoft provides the same authentication flow for Microsoft Accounts (MSA) that Outlook.com uses.

This means you can use the same authentication flow and call the Microsoft Graph to get contacts no matter if they are an Office 365 user or an Outlook.com user. Your app does the same auth flow and makes the same calls.